# A book on discriminant analysis

Tags: machine-learning, references, discriminant-analysis

Can anyone suggest a good book on discriminant analysis - comprehensible and detailed? (Kendall and Stuart write about the subject too concisely.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a chapter on linear and quadratic discriminant analysis in James, Witten, Hastie, and Tibshirani, *[An Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20First%20Printing.pdf)* (pdf freely available online).

Comment: +1, as well as in the more comprehensive *[The Elements of Statistical Learning](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/printings/ESLII_print10.pdf)* by Hastie, Tibshirani, and Friedman.